# SQL like wrapper for Windows Registry?

Tags: sql, windows, registry

The per key handling of updating the registry seems a bit poor when dealing with large volumes of data.  Are there any libraries that would treat all keys as tables and allow INSERTS, UPDATES, or SELECTS in a more programmatic fasion?

Comment: I guess you're in a real trouble if you need to use registry as a database.

Comment: Not in real trouble just sick of the API.

Comment: If you're storing large amounts of data in the registry, you're doing it wrong.  Having said that, something like "Linq to Registry" might be cool...

Comment: I am not all that familiar with Linq can you provide some samples?  I was hoping not to pull in a huge framework.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure if SQL is the best tool to manipulate a tree-like data structure such as the Windows Registry. For me it it sounds like brushing your teeth with a hairbrush.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - "Linq to Registry" doesn't exist (that I know of) - I was just speculating that it would be cool if it did.  Linq in general is a mechanism for doing SQL-like queries against various data stores directly from the C# language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want do do scripting windows powershell has some quite nifty [registry access](http://tfl09.blogspot.com/2007/01/using-registry-with-powershell.html). It handles the registry as if it were a filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

WMI offers access to the registry and has a [SQL like language called WQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

WMI might help, see [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: I can't actually get it to download. :(